# anaconda navigator not installing packages

Tags: python, anaconda

When using a fresh install of anaconda 5.3.0 and attempting to use the navigator to install additional packages into the root environment. I click the little box and see the icon indicating that it will be downloaded and installed, when I click apply and wait for the little loading bar at the bottom to finish the package does not appear to have a check mark indicating that it was successfully installed, further refreshing and restarting the application also don't work. I am at a loss and google has not provided me with much help.

Comment: In order to get some details clear here: At the end of process the navigator GUI still shows that the package is updatable? Did you try to update via command line? Also cross-check with my recent post if your issue is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334344/anaconda-3-package-version-mismatch-between-command-line-and-navigator-gui-sti