# Anaconda 3: Package version mismatch between command line and Navigator GUI (still updatable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I came across a strange situation in setting up my Anaconda3. Several weeks after initial setup I want to update some packages now and as I am friend of command line, I did that via Anaconda prompt opened on my (single) environment via navigator. All cmd statements ran fine and `conda list` gives the expected version numbers. **However, the navigator GUI still flags related packages as "updatable". What is the reason for it?** Thanks for fruitful discussions and learnings about anaconda!

Particular examples:

- python -> navigator shows *update possible to 3.7.7*, but `python --version` says 3.7.7
- pytorch -> navigator shows *update possible to 1.3.1*, but `conda list -f pytorch` for environment cmd prompt says 1.3.1

My system setup:

- Windows 10 1909 x64 with conda version 4.8.3 and conda-build version 3.18.11
- Anaconda3 installed in a C:\ folder -> for package maintenance activities always admin rights used
- One single conda environment -> base (root)
- One single update channel configured in Navigator GUI -> defaults
- All packages installed via conda, nothing via pip

```
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
```

What I tried so far:

- During search on Stackoverflow, I stumbled across the following question, BUT this is a different problem: [problems updating packages in anaconda navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109471/problems-updating-packages-in-anaconda-navigator)
- Also on Stackoverflow, a question in this particular was posted, BUT the user used pip which I did not use: [Anaconda Navigator shows me old versions of packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975333/anaconda-navigator-shows-me-old-versions-of-packages)
- The "To update all current packages without upgrading to the latest version of Anaconda" approach mentioned in following link, but did not work: 
  https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#conda-update-anaconda-command-does-not-install-the-latest-version-of-anaconda
- Removal and Re-Installation of anaconda-navigator package